# HTML form sent by Ajax and handle with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form input generated with PHP like given below:

```
<input type="text" name="category[type]">
<input type="text" name="category[name]">
```

In PHP, it's ok. But I need to send it with javascript by Ajax. I use jQuery and tried with function `$.serializeArray()` in data.

```
'form': $(this).closest('form').serializeArray(),
```

But the result what I got is:

```
array (7)
  0 => array (2)
    name => "category[type]" (11)
    value => "my_type"
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7ohc2f48/)

Best result what I need is:

```
array
  category => array
    type => my_type
```

or anything similar what I can work with.

Any idea?

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: Post your JavaScript. I have a feeling that you are placing `serializeArray()` line in the wrong place. It should look more like `'data': $(this).closest('form').serializeArray()`

Comment: If you structure your inputs into a `<form>`, you could also just use `$("form").submit()` and it will handle all the data passing for you.

Comment: @cyberbit I added jsfiddle demo

Answer (score 2):

Use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach the `submit` event handler to your form. This will trigger when you click on a submit button within your form.

You want to pass `$(this).serializeArray()` directly into `data` setting.

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'script.php'
        data: $(this).serializeArray(), 
        success: function (res) {
            // handle the response you get back from the PHP
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found out where is a problem. Your solution work correctly but i need to add custom variables which are not part of form.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be better approach get data with `serializeArray`and modify them before sending.

> Custom data must represent the same object as form object which is
>   returned serializeArray.

.

```
var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
    formData.push({ name: 'customParam', value: 'my_val'});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7ohc2f48/1/)

Notice: If you put `serializeArray` directly to the ajax data. It will work correctly.

It might help someone.