# How to convert a $('#form').serializeArray() to c# class object with Ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a model class named Location :

```
  public class Location
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int? Floor { get; set; }
    public string ImgURL { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
  }
```

In my .cshtml.cs Razor page, I have a PageModel named MapLocationModel with a property named CurrentLocation :

```
    [BindProperty]
    public Location CurrentLocation { get; set; }
```

I am using this property within a modal form :

```
<form id="locationForm" method="post">
               
     <!--CurrentLocation.Name-->
     <div class="form-group col-md-9">
         <label asp-for="CurrentLocation.Name" class="control-label"></label>
         <input asp-for="CurrentLocation.Name" class="form-control" />
         <span asp-validation-for="CurrentLocation.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
     </div>

     // Here all other properties
                  
</form>
        
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <input type="button" id="buttonSubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
```

Now what I want to achieve is to pass CurrentLocation to an ajax post.
So far, I have written my ajax function :

```
var button = $("#buttonSubmit");
button.on('click', function () {
    var location = $('#locationForm').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Map/MapLocation?handler=AsyncMyLocationAjax",
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        data: { currentLocation: location },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

But my handler always return null :

```
    public ActionResult OnPostAsyncMyLocationAjax(Location currentLocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(currentLocation);
        // currentLocation is always null
    }
```

I think the problem is that the RequestVerificationToken is part of the serialization  :

[image]

I have read a lot of posts on how to pass data with ajax but I still don't understand how to do it.

What am I doing wrong ? How I can convert `var location = $('#locationForm').serializeArray();` in a `Location` object ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML form sent by Ajax and handle with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669743/html-form-sent-by-ajax-and-handle-with-php)

Comment: first your problem is your jquery fnc. You need handle $form.on('submit'.. for working serializeArray this send form with correct header (multipart/form), second if you want still send data as ajax, you need create correct js object or use .map fnc to your serializeArray result. Check my comment up.

Comment: @daremachine I don't think I have a problem with SerializeArray, this part is working fine (you can see the screenshot, my data are in the array). I also know how to serialize to Json by passing individual properties and then JSON.stringify(). I just want to avoid to recreate my class as Json object in my function. What would be the benefit to serialize a form then ? Also I don't know PHP, so I can't tell if it's working the same way than asp.net.

Comment: that all working same because this is how web applications works. But try add 'FromForm' ... OnPostAsyncMyLocationAjax([FromForm] Location currentLocation)

Comment: No it is not working, I also tried [FromQuery], also changing SerializeArray to Serialize. But none of the 4 combinations works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `serializeArray` and `serialize` will generate `__RequestVerificationToken`,you need post the data by form instead of passing it by json.So change `data: { currentLocation: location }` to `data: location` like below:

```
var button = $("#buttonSubmit");
button.on('click', function () {
    var location = $('#locationForm').serializeArray();
    console.log(location);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Map/MapLocation?handler=AsyncMyLocationAjax",
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        data: location,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! It is working. I feel so stupid, seems it was so simple. Again, thank you for your time.